# Cannot open xaml pages in Blend after installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 (CTP)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, projects-and-solutions, expression-blend-5

I am experiencing something weird at the moment. After I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 (CTP), I can no longer open xaml pages properly in Blend designer view.

Looks like everything from other namespaces just cannot be found (see screenshot below)...

[image]

Please also note that the whole solution compiles ok if I close up all the xaml pages, and runs well too. But as soon as I open any of the xaml pages, it will throw me those errors...

**UPDATE 13 MAY 2013**
Just an update, a couple of days ago (after I installed the VS Update 2) the same error came back again. What I did to fix this was I had to change my build name from something else to 'Release' (or 'Debug') and did a 'Clean' and 'Build'.

Comment: I can certainly take a look to help. If you can get in touch offline at unnir at Microsoft dot com to share a repro, that would be great. Can you confirm:
a) You can reproduce this issue on multiple machines?
b) Can you reproduce this with a Blank Windows Phone 8 project that uses this property? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I just sent you an email. :)

Comment: I have the same problem, and have asked a question on [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/58f7e77b-bc58-40e0-a417-91a4493cc0b6) but still no solution yet. Installing VS 2012 Update 2 did not help.

Comment: Hi @Xenan, can you please tell me the name of the build you are using in your visual studio when you try to open it in Blend? If you are not using either 'Debug' or 'Release', try changing it to one of them and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

Updating to Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 should fix the issue: http://microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=38188

Comment: I did install this one. :(

Comment: Try installing the new version. CTP update 4 is out ! Maybe this fixes your issues?

Comment: If you could update your link to http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=38188 then I will accept your answer. :) After installing update 2 it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the platform configurations for all projects linked together in the solution match ("Any CPU" or "x86").  For more info, see:

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/04/05/blend-for-visual-studio-2012-platform-errors/

This also seems to be a problem with the RTW version of VS2012 Update 2.  I experienced this with a solution containing WP8 and Win8 Metro projects.

Comment: Thanks, but I had it set to 'Any CPU'. :(