# C# WPF Error Code 32 When Loading XAML Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was ready to run my project, then i pressed CTRL + Z about once or twice.
 Then the XAML designer dumped.

And it's also happen to all my other projects, even i created new project and new xaml.

1. Repair vs installation.
2. Run as administrator.
3. Delete everything in ShadowCache.
4. I have reinstalled vs, https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller using this tool to clean my registry, the problem remains.

Methods above can not fix my problem.

**Reinstallation didn't work for me. I installed vs2015 enterprise, now I can back to work.**

**As for vs2013, is there still a way to fix it? Or I have to reinstall my windows?**

This is the error code.

> System.InvalidOperationException Error Code 32.

You can see the details on the screenshot. Thank you for your helping.

[image: Error Code 32]

Comment: Try to repair your VisualStudio installation

Comment: Try running your Visual Studio environment as administrator. If that works, check and fix folder and file permissions in the VS installation folders.

Comment: You can try a [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe) first. Btw, attaching an image of exception isn't nice.

Comment: @vasily.sib Sorry about that, I will try to avoid that next time. Without safe mode I can still run the project successfully, running safe mode didn't help me solve this problem.

Comment: @Freggar Already done, didn't work.

Comment: @dlatikay Same problem, didn't work too.

Comment: then, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871358/visual-studio-2012-xaml-designer-invalid-markup

Comment: @vasily.sib I tried to delete everything in shadowcache, still not working.

Comment: then all I can advise is: try to google for something like "Visual Studio cleanup", sorry:(

Comment: @vasily.sib Anyway, thank you for your helping.

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: @Tony VS2013 ultimate running on win10.

Comment: Give a try at Visual Studio 2017 Preview. I use only this.https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Comment: @Tony I am trying vs2015 enterprise right now, vs2017 got some compatibility issues with my coworks' codes.

Comment: Maybe try running devenv.exe as administrator - this looks like it is trying to save some caching file to a temp location, and it does not have access to do so? The actual exe is found in a similar path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE 
EDIT: sorry I only see now you have already tried that.